# Compilation error when including boost/thread.cpp

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio, boost-thread

I have the following code using Boost ASIO to setup a TCP client. Here is my code adapted from the Boost doc's [chat example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_client.cpp).

```
class AsioCommunicationService {
AsioCommunicationService::AsioCommunicationService(
        boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
        tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
    : io_service_(io_service),
      socket_(io_service)
{
    tcp::endpoint endpoint = *endpoint_iterator;
    socket_.async_connect(endpoint,
    boost::bind(&AsioCommunicationService::handle_connect, this,
    boost::asio::placeholders::error, ++endpoint_iterator));
}

void AsioCommunicationService::handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error,
        tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
{
    if (!error)
    {
      boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(read_msg_.data(), LampMessage::header_length),
          boost::bind(&AsioCommunicationService::handle_read_header, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
}
}


class Connection
{
    //init io_service, query, resolve, iterator here
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(host, service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator =
  resolver.resolve(query);


    m_session = std::shared_ptr<AsioCommunicationService>(
            new AsioCommunicationService(io_service, iterator));

    //start new thread for io_service.run --> GOT AN ERROR when include boost/thread.hpp
    boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));

    //this synchronous command would work, but it's blocking the program. I don't want that.
    //io_service.run();
}
```

Of course, I needed to include boost/thread to make the declaration to variable t in class Connection works. But when I did so, I got this error

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
//ERROR: In function ‘boost::thread&& boost::move(boost::thread&&)’:
///usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:349:16: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘boost::thread&&’ from expression of type ‘boost::thread’
//In file included from /usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread_heap_alloc.hpp:17:0,
//             from /usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:13,
//             from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:22,
//             from /usr/include/boost/thread.hpp:13,
//             from /home/son/dev/logistics/src/frameworks/networkService/NetworkConnection.cpp:13:
///usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_heap_alloc.hpp: In function ‘T* boost::detail::heap_new(A1&&) [with T = boost::detail::thread_data<void (*)()>, A1 = void (*&)()]’:
///usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:130:95:   instantiated from here
///usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_heap_alloc.hpp:24:47: error: cannot bind ‘void (*)()’ lvalue to ‘void (*&&)()’
///usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:43:13: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘boost::detail::thread_data<F>::thread_data(F&&) [with F = void (*)()]’
```

It would compile and work if I remove the include to boost/thread.hpp, and replace the declaration to t by a simple call to io_service.run(); I'm wondering if this compilation error has to do with boost version. I'm using Boost ASIO 1.42, Ubuntu 11.04 and Eclipse if those are of any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you try to strip this down to a small self-contained example, so people can experiment with it?

Comment: Boost 1.42 is quite dated (from 2010 afaics). At least some of the error messages refer to rvalue references, which are part of the C++11 standard and must have been pretty bleeding edge at that time. There might still have been a number of rough edges. I'd try a recent version of boost and see whether that solves your problems.

Comment: thanks @MvG, basically I got those errors when I put the include <boost/thread.hpp> in my code. The rest doesn't concern I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much exploration, following @MvG suggestion, I successfully compiled and linked my simple program by doing the following:

- manually build and install boost 1.50 (using MvG suggestion)
- compile and link the source using the following 2 make files (1 for static and 1 for dynamic linking).

Dynamic:

```
default: test

test.o: test.cpp
    g++-4.5 -std=c++0x -I /home/son/boost_1_50/include/ -c test.cpp 

test: test.o        
    g++-4.5 -std=c++0x -L /home/son/boost_1_50/lib/ test.o -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_chrono -pthread -o test

run: test
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/son/boost_1_50/lib/ ./test
```

Static:

```
default: test

test.o: test.cpp
    g++-4.5 -std=c++0x -I /home/son/boost_1_50/include/ -c test.cpp 

test: test.o
    g++-4.5 -std=c++0x -L /home/son/boost_1_50/lib/ test.o -static -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_chrono -pthread -o test

run: test
    ./test
```

The test.cpp file is as follows.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("boost thread tested by son\n");
    boost::thread t;
    return 0;
}
```

That's it. I'm having difficulties compiling this with CMake but that's another problem.

Comment: The `-static` linking not only links in boost statically, but large parts of libc and libstdc++ as well. Not sure whether that really is a good idea.

Comment: yeah, statically linking directly to the .a as you explained is another alternative way. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a single file containing a single include directive:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
```

- `g++-4.5.4 -std=c++0x -I /usr/include/boost-1_42 -c` gave the errors you mention.
- `g++-4.6.3 -std=c++0x -I /usr/include/boost-1_42 -c` the same
- `g++-4.7.1 -std=c++0x -I /usr/include/boost-1_42 -c` gave even more errors
- `g++-4.7.1 -std=c++0x -I /usr/include/boost-1_49 -c` has not a single error
- `g++-4.6.3` and `g++-4.5.4` also work without error using boost 1.49

So I'd really suggest you use a more recent version of boost for this. You don't have to install it system-wide, but instead can install it for a single user. So you are not dependent on ubuntu packages.

To manually install boost, I suggest you follow the [Getting Started on Unix Variants](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) guide:

1. Untar [`boost_1_50_0.tar.bz2`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.50.0/) to some temporary source directory and `cd` into that
2. [Build and install](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install) using `./bootstrap.sh --prefix=${HOME}/boost_1_50 && ./b2 install`
3. [Compile](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#build-a-simple-program-using-boost) your application using `-I ${HOME}/boost_1_50` to get correct headers
4. Include `${HOME}/boost_1_50/lib/libboost_thread.a` as an argument when [linking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library) your application

Using the static `libboost_thread.a` as opposed to the dynamic `libbtoost_thread.so` will ensure that you don't have to worry about locating libraries to launch your application. Everything from boost which you need will be included in your main binary.

Comment: Thanks. How'd you suggest me to install boost 1.49 or 1.50 on my ubuntu natty? I can't seem to find a ppa for it. Should I download and re-compile boost then?

Comment: @SonDo, I included a quick guide on installing boost in my answer.

Comment: thanks @MvG. I succesfully built and install boost (but I got a few ignored, and skipped. I don't know why). Then compiling my sample code with this "g++-4.5 -std=c++0x -I ${HOME}/boost_1_50 test.cpp -c" still gives me the same error. Hmm, I'm getting really mad now, spending 2 days on this thing without any progress. I'd really appreciate it if you can help me figure that out.

Comment: and also can you tell me how to install different version of g++ on the same machine? thanks.

Comment: @SonDo, compile with `-E` to only run the preprocessing phase. The result should tell you which header files actually were included. That should tell you whether the old headers were used by accident. As for installing g++: follow [the manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/) to install that with a `--prefix` somewhere under your `${HOME}` as well.

Comment: thanks a lot @MvG. I wanted to choose your answer as the best but it didn't contain all the info I used to compile. I'm really sorry. I put my own answer there so other people can use it too.

Comment: @SonDo, never worry, accept what answer you think best describes the overall solution.

Answer (score 1):

Following the line of reasoning of @MvG of C++11 standard, I did some research. It seems that it's [a problem of coordination](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/boost1.42/+bug/776860) between gcc and boost provided with Ubuntu Natty, which used -std=c++0x and libboost1.42, respectively.

There's no solution for it, but I used this workaround: commenting out `# define BOOST_HAS_RVALUE_REFS` in /usr/include/boost/config/compiler/gcc.hpp as follows.

```
#if (__GNUC__ > 4 || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ > 2)) && defined(__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__)
// C++0x features are only enabled when -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x are
// passed on the command line, which in turn defines
// __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__.
# define BOOST_HAS_DECLTYPE
//# define BOOST_HAS_RVALUE_REFS
# define BOOST_HAS_STATIC_ASSERT
# define BOOST_HAS_VARIADIC_TMPL
#else
```

My code compiles like magic now:) Thanks @MvC.